# Send Sms With Genymotion

Tags: android, sms, emulation, genymotion

I'm new android developer and I want to Test an app works with sms service . i want to test my app with Genymotion emulator but I cant find a way to send message !
Is there any way to send and receive SMS with Genymotion emulator ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, for the moment, you cannot send/receive SMS with Genymotion.
This is still in the "todo list" of the Genymotion dev team (I'm part of it).

Comment: is there any specific time to do it ?

Comment: how about now..?

Comment: Now in 2015, is it still impossible?

Comment: I will ask about this in 2016

Comment: It does support SMS as of version 2.4.0. Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o-0EIz05zw