# How to send sms to my Genymotion virtual device?

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I used the emulator of Android Studio for testing my app before. There's a popup dialog activity that appears whenever there's a new incoming sms. I used telnet localhost 5554 for sending sms to the emulator, but the emulator was very slow, often crashed (not strong enough pc) so I installed genymotion just now, which runs great, but I can't use telnet to send sms to that virtual device. How can I do it then?

Or is there an easy way to send free sms to my actual Android device, that would be fine too for a solution ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Sms With Genymotion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210791/send-sms-with-genymotion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there's a built in feature for this in genymotion, but only in the business version for 25 euro / month :( I'm just doing this app as a collage assignment, not for profit, but looks like i'm stuck with the Android Studio emulator then.